# Onkey up Second input value should not be greater than first value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeydown, onkeyup

I have three input values one for payment, second for advance payment
 and third for remaining balance from actual_payment to advance_payment.

If the advance payment is greater than acutal payment, the advance payment should not be enter.

```
<input type="text" id="actual_payment" value="">
<input type="text" id="advance_payment" value="">
<input type="text" id="balance_payment" value="">
```

How to compare advance payment should not greater actual payment and remaining balance should not be greater than actual payment and advance payment.

Here is my jquery code

```
    $(function(){
        $("#advance_payment").on('keyup', function(){
            var actual_payment = $("#actual_budget").val();


            $("#balance_payment").val(actual_payment-$(this).val());    
            if ($("#advance_payment").val()>$("#actual_budget")) {
                alert("sorry the advance payment should be less actual payment");
            }

        })  
        });
```

Comment: You're probably getting `NaN` in the results, because you're subtract strings, try changing the type of those inputs to `number` (or parse the value using `parseInt`), also it should be `if ($("#advance_payment").val()>$("#actual_budget").val())`

Comment: Actually instead of `$("#actual_budget")` in the `if()`, it should probably be `actual_payment`.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns a string:

```
$("#actual_budget").val()
```

You probably want to use the [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function:

```
parseFloat($("#actual_budget").val());
```

That will apply to any field that you retrieve as a decimal number.